# How to zoom the selected image

Tags: android, carousel, zooming

I am new in android . I am using carousel and i want to zoom the selected image.  This is my carouseladapter class here i am receiving the position of selected image inside the getView() method .Any help regarding this is very helpful for me in understanding this concept.

```
public class  CarouselAdapter  extends BaseAdapter {

        private ArrayList<ImageView> mData = new ArrayList<ImageView>(0);
        private Context mContext;

        public CarouselAdapter(Context context) {
            mContext = context;
        }

        public void setData(ArrayList<ImageView> data) {
            mData = data;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mData.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int pos) {
            return mData.get(pos);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int pos) {
            return pos;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            ImageView mImage= mData.get(position); //new ImageView(mContext);
            Log.v("UITEST", "position: " + position);
    //      mImage.setImageResource(mData.size());
            //mImage.setScaleType(ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            //mImage.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
            //mImage.setBackgroundResource(R.drawableble.slider_bg);
            return mImage;
        }


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this to zoom the image onItemSelectedListner

```
View lastSelectedView=null;



this.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                    int arg2, long arg3) 
            {   
                if(lastSelectedView!=null)
                    lastSelectedView.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(200, 200));
                arg1.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(400, 250));

                lastSelectedView=arg1;


            }
```